# typescript error on auth.js "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.5", session callback

Tags: session, next.js, callback, next-auth

I'm having type script error in session callback method:

```js
async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken || "";
      session.user.department = token.department || "";
      session.user.companyName = token.companyName || "";
      session.user.jobTitle = token.jobTitle || "";
      return session;
    },

enter code here
```

When I hover on session I see this error:

[image]

and I have extended Session and JWT types in auth.d.ts file

```js
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession, DefaultUser, DefaultJWT } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    name: string;
    email?: string;
    image?: string;
    accessToken?: string;
    department?: string;
    jobTitle?: string;
    companyName?: string;
  }

  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: User;
    expires: DateTime;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT extends DefaultJWT {
    accessToken?: string;
    department?: string;
    jobTitle?: string;
    companyName?: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `{ session: Session; token: JWT }`. Also, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: This fixed the issue:
'async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token?: JWT }) {
      ...
    },'